# Why does Vitest coverage report a file that just exports an enum?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, next.js, istanbul, vitest

We operate on a 100% branch coverage policy. We do not track functions or lines. We find that to be the best balance between code coverage and productivity. We currently have a problem where vitest is reporting the following file as having two branches:

[image]

```js
export enum URL {
  preSignedUploadUrl = '/case-document/upload/api?fileType=',
  saveDocumentUploadToMongoUrl = '/case-document/upload/api?caseReference=',
}
```

If I add the following tests, the branches are covered, but as you can see, they are not unit tests and serve no valuable purpose

```
import {describe} from 'vitest'
import {URL} from '@config/urls'

describe('urls', () => {
  it('has the correct URLs', () => {
    expect(URL.preSignedUploadUrl).toEqual(
      '/case-document/upload/api?fileType=',
    )
    expect(URL.saveDocumentUploadToMongoUrl).toEqual(
      '/case-document/upload/api?caseReference=',
    )
  })
})
```

[image]

**Config**

```
const config = {
  plugins: [react()],
  test: {
    coverage: {
      provider: 'istanbul',
      reporter: ['cobertura', 'json', 'html', 'text-summary'],
      reportsDirectory: './coverage',
      branches: 100,
      all: true,
      include: ['**/*.ts', '**/*.tsx'],
      exclude: ['**/*.spec.ts', '**/*.spec.tsx', '.next/*'],
      src: process.cwd() + '/src',
    },
    setupFiles: './setupTests.js',
    exclude: [...configDefaults.exclude, './.next/'],
    environment: 'happy-dom',
  },
}

export default defineConfig(config)
```

Comment: Are those enum values not actually getting _used_ in the code that was already being tested? Note that an enum may look simple but is transpiled to non-trivial JS: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings.

Comment: you're right, they are not tested yet, but they are also not branches (so far as I understand a branch to be)